# Is it poor practice to use HTML interpolation to change CSS styles in Angular2+?

Tags: angular

My goal was to change the CSS styling when a user was on desktop or mobile device. So, I started by using an observable to return if the width of the window is greater than 1000px.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Hitsuji';
  private screenSize = new BehaviorSubject<string>('small');
  cast$ = this.screenSize.asObservable();

 constructor( public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.breakpointObserver
      .observe(['(min-width: 1000px)'])
      .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
        if (state.matches) {
          this.changeScreenSizeBig();
        } else {
          this.changeScreenSizeSmall();
        }
      });
  }

  changeScreenSizeBig() {
    this.screenSize.next('big');
  }
  changeScreenSizeSmall() {
    this.screenSize.next('small');
  }
}
```

Then I subscribed to the observable cast$ and used it in conjunction with my HTML to change CSS styles.

**projects.component.ts**

```
import { AppComponent } from './../app.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  picNum = 1;
  curScreenSize: string;
  constructor(public app: AppComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.app.cast$.subscribe(screenSize => (this.curScreenSize = screenSize));
  }

  next() {
    if (this.picNum === 4) {
      this.picNum = 1;
    } else { this.picNum = this.picNum + 1; }
  }

}
```

**projects.component.html**

```
<img class="{{ curScreenSize }}" src="/src/assets/project{{ picNum }}.jpg" />
```

So, I'm changing my `img class` with `curScreenSize`, and I've got a css styles based on the two different names `curScreenSize` could be. Could this be done a more elegant way?

Comment: Sometimes you need to do stuff ok this, but in this case why not just use media queries?

Comment: I think there are cases when you can use css in the way you have described, but media queries are designed for this purpose.

Comment: I'll look into using media queries, thank you @IngoBürk and Dean

Comment: media queries are the right call for what you're trying to do, but sometimes you will need something like this... In that case you might want to look into building custom directives to isolate responsibility rather than wiring this logic into every component on an ad hoc basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been said in the comment section, there are [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), and seems to fit better your needs, since you are only caring about the screen size. If you were to check the user agent however, it would require javascript for sure to do the job and check if you are on a chromium, safari, etc.

#### Media Query

For the media query approach, you just have to declare `min-width` tier to separate the desktop style from the mobile style (there are other ways to achieve the goal, this is just an example for the sake of the answer). So you would end up with something like the css bellow:

```
/* Mobile Style */
@media (max-width: 999px) {
  img {
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Desktop Style */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  img {
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

#### Programmatically (javascript)

In addition, in case you decide to use the javascript approach, I would recommend changing only the body class to `mobile` or `desktop` and style according to that parent class. For exemple:

```
.desktop img {
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
}

.mobile img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

So that you don't have to worry about many subscriptions across many components therefore changing only one class at the body tag and styling everything else based on those classes.